# Почему функция не всегда возвращает null?

Tags: javascript, функции

Возник вопрос при анализе кода.

Почему функция binarySearch не всегда возвращает null, несмотря на то, в конце функции прописан return null. Как на это влияет return mid в массиве?

Спасибо!

```js
const binarySearch = (list, item) => {
  let low = 0;
  let high = list.length - 1;

  while (low <= high) {
    const mid = Math.floor((low + high) / 2);
    const guess = list[mid];

    if (guess === item) {
      return mid;
    }
    if (guess > item) {
      high = mid - 1;
    } else {
      low = mid + 1;
    }
  }

  return null;
};

const myList = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];

console.log(binarySearch(myList, 3)); // 1
console.log(binarySearch(myList, -1)); // null
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`return mid` в цикле останавливает цикл, останавливает функцию, и возвращает значение. До последнего `return null` в таком случае дело просто не доходит. Таким образом можно прервать любую вложенность циклов и функцию, и из любой глубины возвратить значение.